# Shall I quit academia or continue doing research without too much luck?

Tags: postdocs, job

My first three year postdoc was almost over and no good publications came out. The thing is that my carefully crafted papers are getting rejected again and again by decent journals (not that good ones). Knowing how bad the academic job market is now, I have a feeling that I may not make it in academia. I could do another postdoc after my 3 year contract or probably choose to quit.

If I am bad at research, I would quit now for sure. It is just that somehow my mentor has been supportive of me staying in academia and she is very famous. She can't be too wrong, right? Also, I got many projects going well. I think I am pretty good at research. I hope one of those projects will end up in a good journal.  But, it has been three years after my phd.

I came to Europe to do a phd as a poor Chinese guy. At the time, I didn't know much about English and only learned my current major though a 3 year master program in China. I worked hard and learned fast to catch up. But, things just wouldn't click. I did my job but the journals just wont accept my papers. Bad luck? probably. Or, something wrong with my topic or approaches.

If I do another postdoc, I will be way over 30. My life already suffered from my research career. A lonely Chinese guy in a foreign country. No money. No nothing. Just my research. Another postdoc without much hope of making it in academia could cause damages to my life, from which I may never recover.

Shall I finish more projects and try my luck to do another postdoc ? Or just quit, even though people say i am good. Being good isn't very useful in academia I guess. Only papers count.

Comment: Sorry to hear of your difficulties. I'm not sure we can assess your situation better than you can -- obviously permanent positions are hard to come by, and papers do count for a lot, but a strong researcher does a non-zero chance of a faculty job. I do suggest you research other options before committing to another post-doc -- academia is not the only place where interesting research happens, and it is a huge weight off your shoulders once you have a permanent position and can move forward with your life. Good luck.

Comment: I hope you are on a continual job hunt, not just at the end of a post doc contract. It can take a lot of time to bring it to fruition. But it sounds like you have a lot of ideas that can be exploited. That is independent of the state of the job market.

Answer (score 9):

You write "My life already suffered from my research career." This is worrying.
Think about this: what do you need the most for a satisfying life? Is it being close to home? Having a fulfilling relationsship? Having a garden? Living in China? Living near the sea? Being a researcher? Find out what it is for you and focus at first on that. Then find out what else you can do while realising your first priority.

Don't get too hung up on Academia. Being a researcher is not a higher calling from some God, at the end of the day it's just a job. There are many good and satisfying jobs out there. Find out what else the world has to offer.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a question in your post we can answer -- you're having difficulties in your job and your life but what you should do is a very individual question: what is it that matters to you.

But I'll try to address one part of your post: Your papers are getting rejected. Most of the time, you will have gotten feedback of some sort on these papers. What do reviewers say? That the paper has a good idea but is poorly written? That the paper has a good idea, but that others have already done that and published a few years ago? That the paper does not have a good idea and that, while well executed, the question the paper tries to answer is simply not very interesting? In all of these cases, there is something to be learned from the feedback you get, and it should inform your future approach to both research and paper writing. I am a bit surprised that none of this feedback has found its way into your post.

So my suggestion is this: There is a saying in English that "insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting a different outcome". So sit down and think through what feedback you got on your manuscripts, and how you would have to change your approach to writing papers and, maybe more generally, doing research. For example:

- If reviewers say your papers are poorly written, then start writing papers with co-authors who are good writers.
- If reviewers say that your papers do not show anything new, then start reading more -- pick the newest issues of the journals in your area and just read random articles related to your work to see what others are doing.
- If reviewers say that your ideas are just not interesting, then have more conversations with your adviser about whether something is worth pursing or not.

Comment: well, I got reviews saying the writing had problems for my first paper. But, the most recent experience was two reviewers saying the paper was well written. One reviewer said this was deadly wrong and the fourth one failed to understand the math behind it and was very negative about complicated analyses. Rejected ! Writing a paper now to me is quit fast and easy. This might be an illusion from an optimistic  non native  speaker. Anyway, I think it is the topic. I guess i have to admit it now. Anyway, many thanks for your reply. This is kinda a wakening call for me.

Comment: Take these papers and reviews to your adviser and let her talk you through what she sees in them. She will be able to place these reviews in context.

Comment: I'll note that even though I have 20 years of experience and 50+ peer reviewed publications, writing papers is not "fast and easy" for me. It is still a carefully executed and thought through art that requires me to find the best way to explain what I want to say. If your paper writing is fast and easy, you're probably doing something wrong.